# R: Explanation of a multiple linear regression summary

Tags: regression, linear-model, residuals, regression-coefficients

I am quite new with R and while i am able to perform the basics i am not yet able to understand the output results. For example:

`summary(lmodel)` generates the following:

```
Call:
lm(formula = temperature ~ altitude + sea.distance, data = meteodata)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-1.40156 -0.46083 -0.04078  0.50961  1.49844 

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  19.736000   0.257222  76.728  < 2e-16 ***
altitude     -0.016509   0.004006  -4.121 0.000714 ***
sea.distance  0.531111   0.414166   1.282 0.216927    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.7425 on 17 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.864, Adjusted R-squared:  0.848 
F-statistic:    54 on 2 and 17 DF,  p-value: 4.317e-08
```

I know about the `?summary`, `help(summary)` and i am familiar with the basic concepts, but i would kindly ask for some thorough explanation of the summary in regards to my model (`residuals`, `coefficients`, `F-statistic`, `Residual standard error`, etc.).

It seems that there are several similar answered questions in this forum, however none of them macthes exactly my case.

Any help is welcome. Thanks in advance

Comment: The terminology is all standard from any regression text, with the exception of `Residual standard error` which is the conditional variance.  Never did figure out why.

Comment: This question is an obvious duplicate, which you seem to recognize. If previous threads did not provide the information you needed, you should state what you learned from them & what specifically you still need to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The residuals is a five number summary of the residuals from your model; somewhat helpful but plot(lmodel) will show more. The 5 number summary looks fine - the min is opposite the max, the 1st and 3rd quartiles likewise

The coefficients table shows the parameter estimates, their standard errors, associated t and p values

R squared and adjusted r squared are standard measures of how much of the variation in the DV the model is accounting for.

The F statistic is a test of the significance of the entire model

Comment: i was hoping for something more thorough tbh. please take some time expanding your answer so i can accept it

Comment: What do you need explained? I think that, if you don't understand the output with the explanation I gave, you may need to learn more about regression.

Comment: As i explained i am familiar with the basic concepts of statistics, in general. I will accept your answer even though i doesn't  provide much extra